# Same line 3 classes

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to give an explanation based on color of each dot below.

The whole page is:
[image]

My HTML code for the spesific area:

```
<div class="dot-expl">
      <div class ="dot dot-red">Ended</div>
      <div class ="dot dot-green">Running</div>
      <div class ="dot dot-yellow">Ready to start</div>
    </div>
```

My whole CSS code:

```
 .dot-expl{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow:visible;
  }
  
  .dot {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dot-red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .dot-green {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .dot-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

But the result is:
[image]

I cannot find how to give more space between the dots as so as the text can be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with this approach by using the pseudo class `::before` 
I set a margin to each `.dot` on both sides (left & right) to have some space between the individual elements.
You could also give your wrapper a fixed width and use `justify-content` on the wrapper. But I assume this will make you run into other problems depending on the length of the text.

```css
.dot-expl {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: visible;
}

.dot {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dot::before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.dot-red::before {
  background: red;
}

.dot-green::before {
  background: green;
}

.dot-yellow::before {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-expl">
  <div class="dot dot-red">Ended</div>
  <div class="dot dot-green">Running</div>
  <div class="dot dot-yellow">Ready to start</div>
</div>
```